# Why does my logistic regression yield only one class?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I attempted my first machine learning project using a fictional dataset from Kaggle consisting of 1470 records. 84% of records were in the '0' class and 16% were '1's. I used 1200 records to train and test and saved 270 to feed in as new data to see what would happen.  I ended up with a training score of 87% and a test score of 83%, but all 270 records of new data were classified as 0.

Could it be that the data, being fictional, just doesn't make enough of a pattern to teach the machine how to classify?  Or am I doing something wrong?

I've read some of the other posts that seem to concern a similar problem but I don't find a relevant response. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df=pd.read_csv('Resources/train_data.csv')
    
df_skinny =df.drop(['EducationField','EmployeeCount','EmployeeNumber','index',
    'StandardHours', 
    'JobRole','MaritalStatus','DailyRate','MonthlyRate','HourlyRate','Over18','OverTime'], 
    axis=1).drop_duplicates()
    df_skinny.rename(columns={"Attrition": "EmploymentStatus"}, inplace=True)
    df_skinny['EmploymentStatus'] = df_skinny['EmploymentStatus'].replace(['Yes','No'],[1,0])
```

df_skinny['Gender']=df_skinny['Gender'].replace(['Female','Male'],[0,1])
df_skinny['BusinessTravel'] =
df_skinny['BusinessTravel'].replace(['Travel_Rarely','Travel_Frequently','Non-Travel'],[1,2,0])
df_skinny['Department']=df_skinny['Department'].replace(['Human Resources','Sales','R&D'],[0,1,2])

```
df_train=df_skinny[:1200]
df_new=df_skinny[1201:]

X =df_train.drop("EmploymentStatus", axis=1)
y = df_train["EmploymentStatus"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = X_scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression()

classifier.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

print(f"Training Data Score: {classifier.score(X_train_scaled, y_train)}")
print(f"Testing Data Score: {classifier.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)}")

predictions = classifier.predict(X_test_scaled)
print(f"First 30 Predictions:   {predictions[:30]}")
print(f"First 30 Actual Employment Status: {y_test[:30].tolist()}")

new_X = df_new.drop("EmploymentStatus", axis=1)
new_predictions=classifier.predict(new_X)
print(new_predictions)

ynew = classifier.predict_proba(new_X)
print(ynew)

OUTPUT:
Training Data Score: 0.8655555555555555
Testing Data Score: 0.8333333333333334

First 30 Predictions:   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

First 30 Actual Employment Status: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[[1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.00000000e+000 5.24119991e-298]
 [1.00000000e+000 7.88999798e-158]
 [1.00000000e+000 2.73485216e-286]
 [1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
```

Comment: Check if your datasets is balanced or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that 84% of the data is in class 0 and 16% is in class 1. This is very unbalanced data and model will be very biased in this case. That's why you are getting the results mostly as 0.

A good dataset is something that has balanced data among all the classes. So you need to make it balanced using `Random sampling` techniques. There are two kinds of sampling `oversampling` and `undersampling`.

I recommend you to apply sampling techniques to balance your data first.

You can learn more about it from the below article
https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-oversampling-and-undersampling-for-imbalanced-classification/

You can refer this notebook
https://www.kaggle.com/shweta2407/oversampling-vs-undersampling-techniques

Comment: Thank you, Coderina!  Exactly what I need.

Comment: @Michal glad to know that it helped you....you can mark it as answer and upvote it...so that others can also know the solution